# redux saga selectors, how do I access state from a saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

Similar questions have been asked before, but the answers have not been of any help to me.

[What are selectors in redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674200/what-are-selectors-in-redux)

[How to get something from the state / store inside a redux-saga function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772877/how-to-get-something-from-the-state-store-inside-a-redux-saga-function)

I think that I have a different setup since I cannot seem to be able to access state from my saga.

I tried doing:

```
const getList = store => store;
const getList = state=> state;
```

these both return `undefined`.

My store looks like this...

```
export default function createStoreWithMiddleware() {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
    const middleware = [sagaMiddleware, loggerMiddleware];
    const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('reduxState') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reduxState')) : {};

    const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState, compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    ));

    store.subscribe(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
    });

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
}
```

And I want to access my list in this saga:

```
function* selectTender(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield Api.getTenderById(action.payload);
        yield put({type: 'SELECT_TENDER_SUCCEEDED', currentTender: response});
        const list = yield select(getList);
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_CHAPTERS', chaptersList: list, tenderId: response.id});
    } catch (err) {
        yield put({type: 'SELECT_TENDER_FAILED', message: err.message});
    }
}

export function* watchSelectTender(){
    yield takeEvery('SELECT_TENDER', selectTender);
}
```

But like I said, both `state` and `store` are undefined.

So, how do I access my store (or state) in the saga?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You will have to use selectors for that. I'll give a simple example. 
Create a file `selectors.js` and add the fields you want to select from your store, as shown below.

```
export const username = (state) => state.user.name;
```

Then in your saga, import the selectors as,

```
import * as selectors from './selectors';
```

and when you require `username` in your saga, you can simply do,

```
import {select} from 'redux-saga/effects';
...
...
function *sampleSaga(params) {
   const username = yield select(selectors.username);
}
```

the constant `username` in `sampleSaga` will now hold the username value from state.

Comment: I tried that, but like I said, state returns undefined :(

Comment: Actually it worked! I was debugging it wrong. When I used the whole `yield select(selectors.username);` it worked - like magic :)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: can i encapsulate state in function like 
`
function getUserName(params) {
    const username = yield select(selectors.username);
    return username;
}
`

Comment: @ruandao yes, you can, if getUserName is a generator function.

Comment: Thanks! Just, don't forget to put `yield` before `select(...)`...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things may have changed a little. Not sure, the redux-saga docs did not help me out. Could be the way my store is set up. But if you're stuck in 2021, this may help:

I have a state with the property 'currentUser', which in turn has property 'id'. I need the id.

```js
const getUser = (state) => state.get('currentUser')

function* addItem() {
    const currentUser = yield select(getUser)
    const id = currentUser.get('id')
    debugger
}

function* itemQuantitySaga() {
    yield all([takeLatest(INCREASE_ITEM_QUANTITY, addItem)])
}
```

Comment: Do you import state from somewhere in that file?

Comment: It's redux-saga middleware that passes the state as an argument.