# how to get redux state inside saga file

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

i need to get a state from redux, to use it on API call inside the saga file.

i checked about the select API. but its a problem here.

i want to use one function just for the API call. to run this function i need to get the current state from redux. and than put it inside the generator function, i didnt succeed to use the select.

```
    async function getApi(){
// GET THE STATE IN THE NEXT LINE
        try{
            const callByCity = await fetch(`https://www.test.com/APICALL${REDUX STATE}...
`)
            const result= await callByCity.json()
            return result
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
    
    function* fetchMainCity(action){
      try{
        const mainCity = yield call(getApi);
        yield put({ type: "GET_CITY_SUCCESS", result: result})
      } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: "GET_CITY_FAILED", message: "Sorry, We Have A Problem."})
      }
    }
```

Comment: show please how did you use select?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka i tried in a few ways as i seen in some examples.. it didnt work, probably im doing it wrong. ill add it now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redux saga selectors, how do I access state from a saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475888/redux-saga-selectors-how-do-i-access-state-from-a-saga)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a mix of a saga and an `async` function. You can get the state while inside the saga. You can't get it in the `async` function. So if you want to keep getApi as an async function, you will need to get the state first, and then pass it in:

```
function* fetchMainCity(action) {
  try {
    const state = yield select();
    const mainCity = yield call(getApi, state);
    //...etc
}

async function getApi(state) {
  // do stuff with the state
}
```

Alternatively, if you change `getApi` to be a saga, then it can select from the state itself:

```
function* getApi() {
  try {
    const state = yield select();
    const callByCity = yield fetch(`https://www.test.com/APICALL${/* state stuff */}`);
    const result = yield callByCity.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: got it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you could also get a field in your redux state
Let's say your redux state looks like this

```
{ key1: val1 , key2:{}}
```

You could
`const key1 = yield select(state => state.key1)`.
Since normally you would not want to select the whole redux state

Comment: cool! thanks alot!